# asp.net: how to redirect to homepage when no session exists for web user?

Tags: asp.net, session

I have a web app with loads of pages and most of them require some session variables in order to function.

i want to put some defensive code in my master page's page_load or init events to detect if the user has a session (meaning any session variable instead of a particular variable) and if not redirect them to the homepage to start all over.

whats the best way to do this? should i use session_end instead?

a simple solution for this would be best.

EDIT:
so i am guessing the master page is the place i want to add this to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not just go:

```
if(Session.Count == 0)
{
    // no session variables
}
```

?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the count of session variables and if it equals 0, then redirect.

```
If Session.Count = 0 Then
    'Redirect
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The session is created as soon as the user enters your site. To detect if the session was created the way you wanted it, set a property in the session like

```
Session["is_valid"] = true
```

Check on other pages if this is set, and if not, `Page.Redirect` the user to the appropriate page.